# Retrieving binary titles from the Broker DB

Tags: dd4t, odata, metadata, broker

I am currently writing an indexer to put SDL Tridion Content into a search engine. The content includes Component Presentations, Pages and Binary Variants. I need to retrieve a Title for each of these. The content is published using DD4T templates.

This is working well for Pages and Component Presentations, but the Title for Binaries in the Broker DB (in the `items` table, and consequently in the objects returned by OData and the API are in the form of "tcd:pub[24]/componentmeta[42956]".

Is this expected behavior? I was hoping to see the title that an editor inserts for naming the Multimedia Component in Tridion.

Is this specific to DD4T, or just how default Tridion handles inserting binaries in the database? Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Can you share the code / OData call with which you retrieve the title? Additionally, is this call being done the first time you publish that binary?

Comment: In my odata Binary Varants, the title of the binaries are in the form of url path to the image as you expected, even in a publication with dxa (dd4t publication)

Comment: And in the database they appear as you said, with tcd:pub[6].. for all publications, dd4t and normal ones

Answer (score 1):

The "Title" you are obtaining for Binary objects comes from the **Component** collection of OData.

For Binary objects, to obtain the name of the file you can access it by menas of the Binary Collection, extended with **BinaryVariant**. Something like:

```
.../odata.svc/Binaries(BinaryId=354,PublicationId=6)/BinaryVariants
```